# f:ajax tag executes the whole form instead of the given element

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have two f:ajax tags in my xhtml document and each ajax tag is configured to render two different elements. However, triggering any one of these tag renders the whole form.

```html
<h:body>
 <h:form>
  <h:panelGrid id="externalUsers" columns="3" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
   <h:selectOneRadio id="fruits" value="#{login.fruit}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="apple" itemLabel="Apple"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="banana" itemLabel="Banana"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="grape" itemLabel="Grape"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="cherry" itemLabel="Cherry"/>
   </h:selectOneRadio>
   <h:commandButton value="Check Match" id="fruitButton">
    <f:ajax execute="fruits" render="fruitMessage"></f:ajax>
   </h:commandButton>
   <h:outputText id="fruitMessage" value="#{utility.retrieveMessage()}"/>
   <h:inputText id="credsType" value="#{login.credType}">
   </h:inputText>
   <h:commandButton value="CheckCreds" id="checkButton">
    <f:ajax render="credMessage" execute="credsType" listener="#{utility.changeData}"></f:ajax>
   </h:commandButton>
   <h:outputText id="credMessage" value="#{login.credType}"/>
  </h:panelGrid>
 </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: I think the problem is coming from the `execute` attribute value, try changing the value to @this or remove the attribute and try again. Alternatively you can render both the `fruits` and `fruitMessage` elements.

Comment: @Shahe If I were to replace `execute` attribute value with `@this` then it would render the button but not the `outputText`.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You sometimes say "it renders" whole form, other time it "executes whole form". Those two are very different. Try execute="@this fruits" for first button, execute="@this credsType" for second button. Idependently of what "execute" attribute says, the whole form will be submitted when looking at the browser network log console. If this is a problem, Primefaces <p:ajax partialSubmit="true" .../> might be of interest.

Comment: When I click on "fruitButton" only "fruitMessage" should get rendered. When I click on "checkButton" only "credMessage" should get rendered. But here the whole form is getting rendered when I click on either of these buttons.